# Azure app services isolation and security

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

I have multiple `App Services` hosted on a single `App Service plan` (Basic Small), which is basically a fully managed VM with all it's resources reserved for me. These are all Asp.Net apps.

As I have plenty of resources still available I'm considering moving my WordPress applications to Azure (each to a new `App Service` within the same `App Service plan`.

WordPress unfortunately, has a tendency to get infected every now and then. Also the infection can spread to other websites if they are not properly isolated (infected website may change files of the other websites).

So my question is:

If one of my WordPress websites gets infected are other websites from different `App Services`, but the same `App Service plan` also in danger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to this greatly depends on how you trust Microsoft and their claims.

> All Azure Web Apps (as well as Mobile App/Services, WebJobs and
>   Functions) run in a secure environment called a sandbox. Each app runs
>   inside its own sandbox, isolating its execution from other instances
>   on the same machine as well as providing an additional degree of
>   security and privacy which would otherwise not be available. The
>   sandbox mechanism aims to ensure that each app running on a machine
>   will have a minimum guaranteed level of service; furthermore, the
>   runtime limits enforced by the sandbox protects apps from being
>   adversely affected by other resource-intensive apps which may be
>   running on the same machine.

So it should be secure.

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox